# I accidentally released some of my code, on github, without a licence, what rights (if any) do others have with respect to it?

Tags: licensing, warranty

Also, I didn't disclaim any warranty (which is typically part of the license). Does that mean others can sue for damage? (In the BSD 2-clause license this looks like: "THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.")

Concerning the rights granted, the relevant section (D.5) of the GitHub ToS [1](https://help.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#d-user-generated-content) reads:

> 5. License Grant to Other Users
>
> Any User-Generated Content you post publicly, including issues, comments, and contributions to other Users' repositories, may be viewed by others. By setting your repositories to be viewed publicly, you agree to allow others to view and "fork" your repositories (this means that others may make their own copies of Content from your repositories in repositories they control).
>
> If you set your pages and repositories to be viewed publicly, you grant each User of GitHub a nonexclusive, worldwide license to use, display, and perform Your Content through the GitHub Service and to reproduce Your Content solely on GitHub as permitted through GitHub's functionality (for example, through forking). You may grant further rights if you adopt a license. If you are uploading Content you did not create or own, you are responsible for ensuring that the Content you upload is licensed under terms that grant these permissions to other GitHub Users.

I'm pretty sure that means that the implicit license excludes the right to actually modify the code (that is not part of GitHub's functionality and thus cannot be done on GitHub). How does forking-only (which is at the end of the day only a copy) make sense? Why would they do it this way?

I'm in Germany if that matters.

Comment: As no license means no right to use, how can there be a damage?

Comment: But does github have a default licence?

Comment: @planetmaker Someone could sue for damage caused by using the program.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor They don't call it so, but there are some default rights (linked and excerpted above) which I think is for all intents and purposes a default license.

Comment: @JannPoppinga sure, if it is NOT your code, that might constitute a license infringment. However the question is "I released some of *my* code"

Comment: @planetmaker I'm not talking about license infringements. The scenario is: Someone uses my program, it has a bug, that bug causes damage. Now they sue me for litigation. Could happen bona fide or by a troll lawyer who fabricates such a scenario. I think that is why 2-clause BSD has the warranty disclaimer in.

Comment: @JannPoppinga No-licence also has a warranty disclaimer: You used my code. it is copyright. I did not say you could.Therefore you are in the wrong, not I. (However there may be a default licence. But according to the extract above I see no grant of permission to copy then run the program, because there is no licence to copy off of github)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Ah, yes, I looked it up. [Ex turpi causa non oritur actio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_turpi_causa_non_oritur_actio). I was thinking of the ["burglar sues because he has to eat dog food" case](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/stella-awards/) which turns out to be faked.

Comment: @JannPoppinga Yes I agree partly, but I think that there was not even a contract to break.